# how to pass parameters while calling a function through JSTL

Tags: java, jstl

How can i pass parameters to a function while calling it through JSTL.

```
<c:forEach items="${sessionScope.student_var.details(x)}" var="display_details">   </c:forEach>
```

I am trying to pass parameter x to a function but it is not working

Comment: What is the scope of `x`? Is it a request attribute, request parameter, session attribute, etc?

Comment: @AaronGotreaux X is defined as `<%String x="age"%>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the variable is defined as follows in the JSP:

```
<% String x = "age"; %>
```

You have two options to get the expression to evaluate using `x` as an argument.

**1. Leave the definition as is and set a** `PageContext` **attribute**

```
<% pageContext.setAttribute("x", "age"); %>
```

An expression evaluates variables by looking for attributes by key name. So when your expression is evaluated, the engine is searching for an attribute with the key name 'x' in the pageContext, request, session, and servletContext scopes.

**2. Move the definition of the variable to the backend**

```
request.setAttribute("x", "age");
```

This statement would be found in your servlet/controller, setting the attribute before we reach the JSP.